# Hbase Java API: Retrieving all rows that match a Partial Row Key

Tags: java, hbase

In the Python module [happybase](http://happybase.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), I can retrieve all rows that have a row key starting with a given string (i.e, search using a partial row key).

Let's say I have a rowkey in the format of (ID|TYPE|DATE), I would be able to find all rows with an ID of 1 and a TYPE of A by:

```
import happybase
connection = happybase.Connection('hmaster-host.com')
table = connection.table('table_name')
for key, data in table.scan(row_prefix="1|A|"):
    print key, data
```

This is what I have so far as a totally client side Java program for anyone trying to do the basics using the [Java HBase API](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/index.html), but I can only search for a row using the full row key:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
//class foo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.addResource(new Path("C:\\core-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path("C:\\hbase-site.xml"));
    HTable table = new HTable(conf, "table_name");
    Result row = table.get(new Get(Bytes.toBytes("1|A|2014-01-01 00:00")));
    printRow(row); 
}
public static void printRow(Result result) {
    String returnString = "";
    returnString += Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("id"))) + ", ";
    returnString += Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("type"))) + ", ";
    returnString += Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("date")));
    System.out.println(returnString);
}
//}
```

Where "cf" is the name of the column family.

### ANSWER:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.Filter;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.PrefixFilter;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
//class foo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.addResource(new Path("C:\\core-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path("C:\\hbase-site.xml"));
    HTable table = new HTable(conf, "table_name");
    byte[] prefix = Bytes.toBytes("1|A|");
    Scan scan = new Scan(prefix);
    Filter prefixFilter = new PrefixFilter(prefix);
    scan.setFilter(prefixFilter);
    ResultScanner resultScanner = table.getScanner(scan);
    printRows(resultScanner);
    //Result row = table.get(new Get(Bytes.toBytes("1|A|2014-01-01 00:00")));
    //printRow(row); 
}
public static void printRows(ResultScanner resultScanner) {
    for (Iterator<Result> iterator = results.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        printRow(iterator.next();
    }
}
public static void printRow(Result result) {
    String returnString = "";
    returnString += Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("id"))) + ", ";
    returnString += Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("type"))) + ", ";
    returnString += Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("date")));
    System.out.println(returnString);
}
//}
```

Note that I use the `setFilter` method, whereas the answer below uses the `addFilter` method, on account of us using different APIs.

Comment: Did you face problem with thrift server while using happybase, because when I retrieve huge data using happybase, thrift server breaks whereas for small data retrieval it works.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are using the HTable `get` operation so you're only getting back one row (note that you can specify a prefix here as well and you don't have to give the complete key)

If you want to get back multiple rows you should use a `Scan`

```
byte[] prefix=Bytes.toBytes("1|A|");
Scan scan = new Scan(prefix);
PrefixFilter prefixFilter = new PrefixFilter(prefix);
scan.addFilter(prefixFilter);
ResultScanner resultScanner = table.getScanner(scan);
```

Comment: sorry about that - that's what happens when you edit something without an IDE :) (I had it as just the string then decided not to repeat the Bytes.toBytes() :) )

Comment: Is this the best / only / most efficient way of doing a partial key scan?

Comment: Please note that in HBase 0.98 (and maybe earlier), They changed the API to setFilter. scan.setFilter(prefixFilter);