# How to retrieve information from specific rows from table in Hbase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, nosql

I have a table in Hbase and the key of this table is "user_name" + "id" for example ("username123"). 
I want to retrieve all rows for specific user_name for example (if i have some rows with key "john1","john2"..., i want to retrieve all rows for john)
How can i do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PrefixFilter. For Java API answer is here [Hbase Java API: Retrieving all rows that match a Partial Row Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842469/hbase-java-api-retreiving-all-rows-that-match-a-partial-row-key)

In HBase shell PrefixFilter too:

```
scan 'tablename', {FILTER => "(PrefixFilter ('username'))"}
```